# Google BigQuery: From table of days get a table with all days of year

Tags: google-bigquery, cartesian-product, cross-join

I have this (sample) table:

```
+------------+-------------------+-----------+
|    Date    |       User        | Attribute |
+------------+-------------------+-----------+
| 2019-01-01 | user1@example.com | apple     |
| 2019-02-01 | user2@example.com | pear      |
| 2019-03-01 | user1@example.com | carrot    |
| 2019-03-01 | user2@example.com | orange    |
+------------+-------------------+-----------+
```

I need to create a full permutation of all (date+user) couples filling all the missing days of the year 2019 (with `attribute` as `null`).

Like in my example I have 2 different users:

- user1@example.com
- user2@example.com

The resulting table should be:

```
+------------+-------------------+-----------+
|    Date    |       User        | Attribute |
+------------+-------------------+-----------+
| 2019-01-01 | user1@example.com | apple     |
| ...        | user1@example.com | null      |
| 2019-03-01 | user1@example.com | carrot    |
| ...        | user1@example.com | null      |
| 2019-12-31 | user1@example.com | null      |
| 2019-01-01 | user2@example.com | null      |
| ...        | user2@example.com | null      |
| 2019-02-01 | user2@example.com | pear      |
| ...        | user2@example.com | null      |
| 2019-03-01 | user2@example.com | orange    |
| ...        | user2@example.com | null      |
| 2019-12-31 | user2@example.com | null      |
+------------+-------------------+-----------+
```

The `...` implies that there is a row for each single day of the year, and the `attribute` has a value when the source table provides an actual value, otherwhise a `null` is used.

As first step, to create all the (date+user) permutations I thought of using `bigquery-public-data.utility_eu.date_greg` table, using a `CROSS JOIN` to create all the needed rows.

Here a sample table to be used:

```
#standardSQL
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT DATE('2019-01-01') date, 'user1@example.com' user, 'apple' attribute
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2019-02-01'), 'user2@example.com', 'pear'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2019-03-01'), 'user1@example.com', 'carrot'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2019-03-01'), 'user2@example.com', 'orange'
)
```

And here a first query I attempted:

```
SELECT d.date,s.* EXCEPT(date)
FROM sample s
  CROSS JOIN `bigquery-public-data.utility_eu.date_greg` d 
WHERE d.year = 2019
ORDER BY date,user
```

But this is too much because also the `attribute` values is used inside the join and I'm getting the value replicated on all days that are not related to the original one.

I think I need to have some sort of `DISTINCT` in order to get only the unique (date+user) couples, and only then associate the `attribute` value, if any.

This is first working solution I found:

```
distinct_couples AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT d.date,s.user
  FROM sample s CROSS JOIN `bigquery-public-data.utility_eu.date_greg` d 
  WHERE d.year = 2019
)

SELECT d.*, s.attribute
FROM distinct_couples d
  LEFT JOIN sample s USING(date,user)
ORDER BY date,user
```

But I'm doing a join with `sample` twice (first in temp table and second in main query), so I'm trying to understand if can be optimized.

Do you have any suggestion on how to make it works?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH users AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT user
  FROM `project.dataset.sample`
)
SELECT d.date, u.user, s.attribute
FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_eu.date_greg` d  
CROSS JOIN users u
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.sample` s
ON s.date = d.date
AND s.user = u.user
WHERE d.year = 2019
```

As a side note - you don't really need using any extra dates table as you can generate it on fly - as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH users AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT user
  FROM `project.dataset.sample`
), dates AS (
  SELECT `date` 
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')) `date`
)
SELECT d.date, u.user, s.attribute
FROM dates d  
CROSS JOIN users u
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.sample` s
ON s.date = d.date
AND s.user = u.user
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY`